# How is the safety of ex-presidents in jail guaranteed?

Tags: president, prime-minister, prison

Ex-presidents and ex-prime ministers are surprisingly often convicted of crimes and sometimes sent to jail. [Sarkozy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Sarkozy), [Olmert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehud_Olmert), [Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Myung-bak), [Katsav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Katsav#:%7E:text=On%2022%20March%202011%2C%20Moshe,to%20be%20sentenced%20to%20prison.) , and [Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Geun-hye) are recent examples.

What do countries do about the physical security of these people, assuming they still don't want to them to come to harm?

Comment: US Presidents ans ex-Presidents have extraordinary levels of protection by international standards. Many countries do not provide *any* protection to ex-leaders unless there are specific indications of a threat.

Comment: I think a lot of this depends on the country in question as there are some that almost never or never have convicted one.

Comment: The safety of ordinary prisoners varies a lot between countries and also between individual prisons. If a country has low security prisons for non-violent offenders then maybe that would be considered sufficient. OTOH if the ex-president is considered a political threat then putting them in a high security prison with a high casualty rate might be seen as a good idea by a new incumbent.

Comment: @o.m. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Simd, https://www.news18.com/news/buzz/you-may-bump-into-pm-katrin-jakobsdottir-next-time-youre-strolling-in-iceland-heres-proof-2680753.html is an example of a current head of government without bodyguard. A little country, admittedly.

Comment: @Simd Indian ex-PM Rajiv Gandhi was easily assassinated because at one point the indian government decided that ex-PMs don't deserve VIP security.

Comment: I didn't realise it was so common for ex-premiers to become convicted criminals!

Comment: @Steve There are many more than I have listed too!

Comment: The first sentence is not in agreement with the list given - which includes two Israeli politicians and two South Korean ones. There are specific countries that ordinarily convict their leaders (and prosecute them while in the office), but this is by no means a general thing. Sarkozy is to serve his sentence in home confinement (which is the likely outcome for Trump as well, if this is the one who triggered the question.)

Comment: I do not think this question is about politics, as any answer here would also affect lots of high ranking prisoners (famous, rich, ...) regardless of policies. So I have VtC on those grounds. And even if people do not agree with this point, it is certainly too broad as different countries have different penal systems with different standards and resources.

Comment: Voting to close - this question relates to government policies, and thus is on topic. However, the question is too broad and every country will have their own policy on this. Suggest you edit the question to ask about specific countries (perhaps the ones you cited as examples).

Answer (score 4):

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

They are in jail, so the only people who can "get" them are the other inmates.

The security inside jails is provided by the prison wardens, working under the prison governor.  [See 'Prison Governance'.](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201919/cmselect/cmjust/191/19106.htm)

> A governor is ultimately responsible for everything that happens within a prison [... including] safety, security and rehabilitation.

For high profile prisoners, or other who may be at greater risk from other inmates (such as sex offenders, particular child abusers) special security arrangements may be made. This could mean isolation from other inmates, or individually tasked wardens. Governors have a duty to keep prisoners safe and secure, and the operational independence to do that.

Not all prisoners are equal in terms of the threat they pose, and so not all prisons are equal.  Non-violent prisoners with lower risk of attempted escape are likely to be held under different security conditions from those considered to be more dangerous and more likely to flee.

But the security of prisoners is the responsibility of the Governor, and exercised by the prison wardens and other working for the Governor, such as cooks, office staff etc.

Comment: I don't think that "...so the only people who can 'get' them are the other inmates" is a well-supported assertion by a long shot. There are guards, doctors, lawyers, cooks, staff... if an assassination, threat of violence, or clandestine interrogation is considered valuable enough, there's always ways to make things happen via careful planning, bribery, threats...

Comment: In general people are a lot saver from random assassination attemps inside a prison that outside.

Comment: @quarague assassination is by definition not random.

Comment: The U.K., of course, does not have any ex-Presidents, and its legal system has absolute immunity for a living monarch.

Comment: "guards, doctors, lawyers, cooks, staff"... guards are the ones doing the protecting, so if you can't trust them, all bets are off.  Doctors are employed by the prison, so again part of the protection, cooks - likewise answerable to the governor. Lawyers, no not in prison, except as part of the prisoner's legal team.   No, the only people who might have access to the prisoner who are not employed by the Governer nor employed by the prisoner are the other inmates. - hence the first line of my answer.

Comment: @JamesK yes, all bets *are definitely off!* Both US and UK prison systems are rife with mysterious deaths and not-so-mysterious deaths at the hands of prison guards - there's an established baseline of bi-directional violence and murder.

Comment: Just as a counter to the high profile defence, for the US at least, we can look at the case of Jeffery Epstein. Claims are that he hung himself, but [normal processes weren't followed on the night of his death](https://web.archive.org/web/20200621163709/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/11/nyregion/epstein-death-manhattan-correctional-center.html) - what happens in practice and what procedure says should happen are two quite different things. I'm aware he isn't an ex-president but still shows the system isn't without precedent for failing to look after high profile inmates.